# How can make my Pytorch CNN solver work with varying grid sizes and refinements

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Like said in the title I am trying to improve a Pytorch CNN solver to work over non-uniform grids and non-uniform refinements for a heat transfer. The solver is fully capable with uniform grids and refinements, when having non-uniform characteristics I've tried to make the code to automatically change its tensor shapes to accomodate the changes.

```
`import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator
from matplotlib import cm
import copy

def plot_solution(X,Y,Z):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    surf=ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
    ax.set_title("2D heat Variation, CNN")
    ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
    ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.02f}')
    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5)
    plt.show()
E = 0.001
x = 1
y = 1
Nx = 25 # Points along x-axis
Ny = 25 # Points along y-axis
Px = Nx + 1
Py = Ny + 1
hx = x / Nx
hy = y / Ny
max_iterations = 1000
wei = 1.0
source = 1.0
d = 0
k=1
X = np.arange(0, x+E, hx)
Y = np.arange(0, y+E, hy)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
Z = copy.deepcopy(X)
Z[:,:] = 0.0
wei = 1.
weights = torch.tensor([[0., wei, 0.], \
                        [wei, 0., wei], \
                        [0., wei, 0.]])
weights = weights.view(1, 1, 3, 3).repeat(1, 1, 1, 1)
temperature_conv = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, 3, stride=1, padding=1 )
with torch.no_grad():
   temperature_conv.weight[:,:,:,:] = weights[:,:,:,:]
   temperature_conv.bias[:] = 0.0
solution = torch.zeros(1, 1, Px, Py)
solution[:,:,:,:] = 0.0
src = torch.zeros(1, 1, Px, Py)
src[:,:,:,:] = 1.0
src[:,:,10:22,10:22] = 1.0
diff = torch.zeros(1, 1, Px, Py)
diff[:,:,:,:] = 1.0
sigma = torch.zeros(1, 1, Px, Py)
sigma[:,:,:,:] = 0.0
sigma[:,:,0:int(Px/2),:] = 0
temp_diffusion_diag_coeff = torch.zeros(1, 1, Px, Py)
temp_diffusion_diag_coeff[:,:,:,:] = 1./(diff[:,:,:,:]*(((2+0.5*k)/(hx**2))+((2+0.5*k)/(hy**2))) + sigma[:,:,:,:]) # inverse of main diagonal
temp_diffusion_off_diag_coeff = torch.zeros(1, 1, Px, Py)
temp_diffusion_off_diag_coeff[:,:,:,:] = diff[:,:,:,:]*((0.5/(hx**2))+(0.5/(hy**2)))
for i in range(max_iterations):
 v1 = temperature_conv(solution)
  v1_new =v1*temp_diffusion_off_diag_coeff
  v1_new = v1_new + src
  V1 = v1[0, 0, :, :].detach().numpy()
  V1_new = v1_new[0, 0, :, :].detach().numpy()
  uncertainty = np.max(np.abs(V1-V1_new)**0.5)
  v1 = v1_new
  if uncertainty<E: 
      print("Converged at iteration",i)
      break
  solution = (v1)*temp_diffusion_diag_coeff
if uncertainty>=E:
    print("Solution doesn't converge within the maximum number of iterations") 
    with torch.no_grad():
      Z[:,:] = solution[0,0,:,:].detach().numpy()
    plot_solution(X,Y,Z)
    sys.exit()`
```

Whilst I managed to make the solver run with various tweaks I observed incorrect plots where the peak was not centered and anolmalously high numbers accompannied with bizarre plot shapes.